# How to run htop on remote pc?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, htop

I'd like to use SSH to connect to my PCs from my server and then run `htop`. My old Macs don't have `htop` though.

I got an Ubuntu server as a VM and I'm using it to test this.

- VM-OS: Lubuntu server 14.04
- Remote-OS MacOS 10.6.8
- VM-Server-Name: CLI-Apps-SSH

I'm running it using `VBoxManage startvm "CLI-Apps-SSH" --type headless`.

Then SSH to it for Weechat and hope run `htop`.

Comment: Please have a look at the edit and check whenever it's what you mean. Your original question is pretty hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to stream utilisation information over SSH to a local htop client? This is not possible.

I use htop a lot to monitor remote computers but you *must be able to install htop* on the remote computer.

Macs can run htop but you have to install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (or similar) to do so. You can then connect and run htop.